# Java finalize() call counting

Tags: java, oop, garbage-collection, finalizer

I want to count how many times garbage collector call my finalize method, but i don't know how to implement global variable to do this. I've tried this way:

```
class ObjMaker {

    int obj_nr;

    ObjMaker(int obj_nr){
        this.obj_nr = obj_nr;
    }

    protected void finalize(){
        Global.finalize_counter += 1;
    }
}

public class Global{
    public int finalize_counter = 1;
}

class FinalizeSimpleDemo{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        for(int i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++){
            ObjMaker ob = new ObjMaker(i);
        }
    }
}
```

but this code doesn't work and even doesn't look nice. What is a clever way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `finalize_counter` as a `static` variable. Only then you can access it using the ClassName. Else any instance variable can be accessed only through an instance of the class.

```
public class Global{
    static int finalize_counter = 1; // make it static
}
```

But do note that the JVM implementation controls when the `finalize` is run. In general, `finalize()` method is called when an object is being garbage collected, thus, if no garbage collection is being performed, your `finalize()` may not be called at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good try to be honest since your `finalize()` may to call ever because if this is the only program running. `JVM` will not bother about garbage collecting.

If you really want to count if this going to collect as garbage, you should use `static` variable.

```
   public static int finalize_counter = 1;
```